# SPARQL over JSON-LD data

Tags: mongodb, sparql, virtuoso, json-ld

I have to work with JSON-LD data and to provide SPARQL endpoint as well.
For that, I used Virtuoso, and successfully managed to store JSON-LD data chunks in Virtuoso using the instructions from [JSON-LD, Jena, Virtuoso and Named Graphs](http://hcklab.blogspot.ie/2014/01/json-ld-jena-and-virtuoso-and-named.html).

```
{
    "@context": "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/contexts/system.jsonld",
    "id": "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "type": "city:System",
    "name": "City Live Traffic Data",
    "description": "This is sample desc.",
    "operator": "abc@email.com",
    "serviceArea": "http://dbpedia.org/page/City",
    "status": "city:Available",
    "services": [
        "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/service/configuration",
        "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/service/monitoring",
        "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/service/observation"
    ],
    "sensors": [
        "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/sensor/2-F",
        "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/sensor/3-F",
        "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/sensor/monitoring"
    ]
}
```

However, using SPARQL, I can query the data using Jena ARQ but it does add extra keys to the original JSON-LD data chunk.

```
{
  "@graph" : [ {
    "@id" : "_:t1",
    "rdf:type" : {
      "@id" : "rs:ResultSet"
    },
    "rs:resultVariable" : [ "p", "o", "s" ],
    "rs:size" : {
      "@type" : "xsd:int",
      "@value" : "14"
    },
    "solution" : [ "_:t2", "_:t3", "_:t4", "_:t5", "_:t6", "_:t7", "_:t8", "_:t9", "_:t10", "_:t11", "_:t12", "_:t13", "_:t14", "_:t15" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t10",
    "binding" : [ "_:t41", "_:t42", "_:t43" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t11",
    "binding" : [ "_:t30", "_:t31", "_:t32" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t12",
    "binding" : [ "_:t38", "_:t39", "_:t40" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t13",
    "binding" : [ "_:t45", "_:t46", "_:t47" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t14",
    "binding" : [ "_:t29", "_:t56", "_:t57" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t15",
    "binding" : [ "_:t44", "_:t36", "_:t20" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t16",
    "value" : "http://dmsexample.com/abc@email.com",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t17",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/operator",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t18",
    "value" : "http://104.131.128.70:8080/istanbul-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t19",
    "value" : "http://example.com/arou@ait.edu.gr",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t2",
    "binding" : [ "_:t16", "_:t17", "_:t18" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t20",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t21",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/sensor/3-F",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t22",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/managesSensor",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t23",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t24",
    "value" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t25",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/service/monitoring",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t26",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/providesService",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t27",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t28",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/service/configuration",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t29",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/sensor/monitoring",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t3",
    "binding" : [ "_:t19", "_:t48", "_:t49" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t30",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/IotSystem",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t31",
    "value" : "rdf:type",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t32",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t33",
    "value" : "_:t53",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t34",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/operator",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t35",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t36",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/status",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t37",
    "rs:value" : "City Live Traffic Data",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t38",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/service/observation",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t39",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/providesService",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t4",
    "binding" : [ "_:t28", "_:t54", "_:t55" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t40",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t41",
    "value" : "http://dbpedia.org/page/City",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t42",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/serviceArea",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t43",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t44",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/Available",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t45",
    "rs:value" : "This is sample desc.",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t46",
    "value" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t47",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t48",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/operator",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t49",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t5",
    "binding" : [ "_:t37", "_:t24", "_:t58" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t50",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic/sensor/2-F",
    "rs:variable" : "o"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t51",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/managesSensor",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t52",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t54",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/providesService",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t55",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t56",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/ontology/ns/managesSensor",
    "rs:variable" : "p"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t57",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t58",
    "value" : "http://myweb.com/city-traffic",
    "rs:variable" : "s"
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t6",
    "binding" : [ "_:t50", "_:t51", "_:t52" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t7",
    "binding" : [ "_:t21", "_:t22", "_:t23" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t8",
    "binding" : [ "_:t33", "_:t34", "_:t35" ]
  }, {
    "@id" : "_:t9",
    "binding" : [ "_:t25", "_:t26", "_:t27" ]
  } ],
  "@context" : {
    "solution" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#solution",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "resultVariable" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#resultVariable",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "size" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#size",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "binding" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#binding",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "value" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#value",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "variable" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#variable",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "rs" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#",
    "rdf" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
  }
}
```

My Question is, how can I get the same data-format of ResultSet as of Original Data was pushed?
Or, what are other work around for similar idea? To use other Datastore? or to put SPARQL over MongoDB?

Comment: First thing, it looks like you are doing a SELECT query instead of a CONSTRUCT one, secondly you might need a JSON-LD framing processor to get out JSON in the same tree as you put it in. Now you are getting rawish triples which is not friendly to your JSON tools.

Comment: Yes - that looks like the output of printing a result set encoded as an RDF graph.  It will look nothing like your original data. Try `CONSTRUCT WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }`

Comment: We definitely need to see your SPARQL query; else, we're just (educatedly) guessing at what you *might* have done, and so what you *might* need to do differently. Just in case... you have read over [the official Virtuoso Jena Provider docs](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider), as well as third-party pages, right? There are other Virtuoso doc pages near there which may also be relevant to your needs...